# data recovery from deleted partition

Tags: formatting, data-recovery

i recently merged my hard disk partitions f into c using a partition manager, i didnt need data in f but unfortunately i forgot to backup some important office docs in that partition.

manager formated f and merged the space into c.

is it possible for me to recover from a deleted partition,
how will i do that
thanks

Comment: Make a complete backup image of the whole disk immediately before you do anything that modifies the contents of the disk! If you try something and it fails, you can "reset" from the backup image and try something else.

Answer (score 3):

The files are still there and may be recoverable. Below are listed some utilities to recover files. Just remember when recuperating the files to copy them to another drive than the formatted one, since this will destroy the data. Don't write on the hard disk untill you recover the data.

[PC INSPECTOR File Recovery 4](http://www.pcinspector.de/Sites/file_recovery/info.htm?language=1)

> - Finds partitions automatically, even if the boot sector or FAT has been erased or damaged
> - Recovers files with the original time and date stamp

[Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva)

> **Recovery from damaged or formatted disks**
>  Even if you've formatted
>   a drive so that it looks blank, Recuva
>   can still find your files on it.

[DiskDigger](http://dmitrybrant.com/diskdigger)

> DiskDigger can even scan reformatted
>   or badly formatted disks (disks to
>   which Windows can’t assign a drive
>   letter), and even disks with bad
>   sectors. It bypasses the Windows file
>   system drivers and scans your disk
>   directly.

Comment: is there an option that will recreate f?

Comment: @anique: You "may" be able to return to the previous situation, on condition that f was never overwritten. You'll need to reset c to its EXACT previous size and then recreate the f partition (without reformatting). The chances are slim, but it's possible in theory.

Answer (score 0):

[R-Tools](http://www.r-tt.com/)
 Just a happy customer.