# Data recovery from laptop which was formatted because of new Windows 7 installation

Tags: data-recovery, formatting, hard-drive-recovery, windows-7-restore

I want to recovery my data from an Windows 7 Ultimate installation. My laptop got stolen but later I caught the theft. But unfortunately all my data is lost because he formatted my laptop and put on a new windows installation (because my account had a password).

The problem is that all of the data was important, it contained crucial data from the last 5 years which I shouldn't have lost under any condition.

How can I recover all the data which was in my old Windows installation? Currently there is no data except the fresh Windows installation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [data recovery from deleted partition](http://superuser.com/questions/117439/data-recovery-from-deleted-partition)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *turn of the computer* until you have a recovery plan. The more a drive is used, the less chance of a successful recovery.

If the data is very important, your best chance of recovering its data to visit a specialist who will take the drive and try a number of recovery methods. This can often cost a lot of money depending on the size of the drive, and you also need to choose a company that you can trust. Often cheaper services are less successful and can leave the drive in a worse state after if the recovery did happen to fail.

Should seeking professional support be too expensive or not worthwhile, there are a number of free programs you can try yourself. The best free program for file recovery in Windows in my opinion would be [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva). I have been able to recover files after a format with Recuva, just ensure that you check "enable deep scan":

[image]

This will take a few hours depending on the size of the drive and the number of possible files to recover.

Comment: Not able to detect data on the drive....need more powerful recovery tool with guaranted recovery..

Comment: There is no such thing as a "guaranteed recovery". You can never guarantee data recovery, and all tools work in a similar way. If the data is really *that* important, turn the laptop off now and take it to a specialist as soon as possible.

Comment: If the thieve did not use the "fast" formatting, all data on the partition at least was overwritten.